# why keyError in session when logout?

Tags: django

I set `session["logID"]` in register and login functions in my view but when I want to save it in the DB when user logs out then I get `Loginstatus matching query does not exist.`  in django. here is my functions in `views.py`:

```
def loginProcess(request, email, password):
    try:
        user = authenticate(username=User.objects.get(email=email).username, password=password)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        user = None
    if user is not None:
        # some code here for create LoginStatus model Object
        request.session["logID"] = newLoginStatus.id
        return showProfile(request)
    else:
        return homepage(request)

def logoutProcess(request):
    # ...
    userLoginStatus = Loginstatus.objects.get(pk=request.session.get("logID"))  # I got Error here
    userLoginStatus.sessionData = userSessionData
    userLoginStatus.save()
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

I got the `Loginstatus matching query does not exist.` in server so `session["logID"]` doesn't exist!! but I set it in `loginProcess` and `userLoginStatus` succesfully saved in DB !!!! I don't understand what happens.

Comment: i am not sure what else is happening there, but did you try ``request.session.modified`` right after saving into session in ``loginProcess``?

Comment: @doniyor. it returns `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by debugging in django shell. django twice loads the logout url. `/logout` and `/logout/` the first time user successfully log out but in the second time, `request.session` will be empty and then the line `userLoginStatus = Loginstatus.objects.get(pk=request.session.get("logID"))` throws `ObjectDoesNotExist` Exception then I change the code with `try` and `except` blocks:

```
def saveUserLoginStatusDetails(request):
    userSessionData = Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key).session_data
    userLoginStatus = Loginstatus.objects.get(logid=request.session.get("logID"))
    userLoginStatus.sessionData = userSessionData
    userLoginStatus.logout_date = datetime.now().date().isoformat()
    userLoginStatus.save()


def logoutProcess(request):
    try:
        saveUserLoginStatusDetails(request)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, got the same error at logout time.

solve by (except keyerror)
#Django #python #key error

```
def logout(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            del request.session['email']
            return redirect('login')
    except KeyError:
        return redirect('login')
```